# Execute a program compiled using intel-fortran from MATLAB on Linux machine

Tags: linux, matlab, fortran, genetic-algorithm

I have an executable of a fortran code which I want to run from MATLAB.

I tried using following two options but got errors:

```
!/home/atrac/code case172.jcl
error:- ls: cannot access ./id: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ./id: No such file or directory

!gnome-terminal --command "./home/myhome/code case12.jcl"
error: There was an error creating child process for this terminal
```

Is there a way I can write a shell script to execute the program and pause Matlab till the external program is executed then pass the control back to Matlab?

I am trying to run a genetic algorithm in Matlab, which calls this external software.
Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looks like two different things going on here. Both are probably related to Matlab's current directory.

```
!/home/atrac/code case172.jcl
error:- ls: cannot access ./id: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ./id: No such file or directory
```

Here, it looks like you're managing to run your `code` program, but `code` or the JCL script is looking for a file named `id` in the current working directory. When you shell out from Matlab, that's going to be Matlab's current directory. Run `pwd` from the Matlab command prompt to find out where you are. You can probably fix this by using `cd` in Matlab to move to the directory where the `id` file actually exists (I'm guessing it's in /home/atrac), and then running `code` using the same command line. A better fix would be to rewrite `code` and/or the JCL script to work when run from any path (maybe by using absolute paths), so your cwd doesn't matter.

```
!gnome-terminal --command "./home/myhome/code case12.jcl"
error: There was an error creating child process for this terminal
```

Here, the leading "." is probably messing it up, because it's now looking for `home/myhome` under the current working directory, instead of under the root directory. Try doing `!gnome-terminal --command "/home/myhome/code case12.jcl"` (without the ".") instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, this should go as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation.

But nonetheless, the error with the creating the child process is unrelated to MATLAB. The shell is erroring out. Are you able to run the program from the terminal?

Secondly, you are using:

```
!/home/atrac/code case172.jcl
```

but you should be using
    !./home/atrac/code case172.jcl

Comment: Thanks Lokesh, even i thought that is should be ' !./home/atrac/code case172.jcl' but that doesnt work I get an error: 
/bin/bash: ./home/atrac/code: No such file or directory

Yes I am able to run this program from the terminal

Comment: Can you see whats the shell of your linux?

Comment: Also see try running !ls /home/atrac. This should list all files in the directory. This will at least confirm that the directories are visible.

Comment: No, `!/home/atrac/code` is probably fine. It looks like it's actually running the program, and that's a traditional path to a home directory. The `!./home/atrac/code` command is looking for a `home` subdirectory underneath the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a UNIX program from MATLAB when the folder containing that file is not on the UNIX system path that is visible to MATLAB. To determine the system path that is visible to MATLAB, type the following in the Command Window:

getenv('PATH')

You can make modifications to the system path that persist for the current MATLAB session or across subsequent MATLAB sessions, as described in the sections that follow.

Modify the System Path for the Current MATLAB Session.  Do one of the following:

```
Change the current folder in MATLAB to the folder that contains the program you want to run.

Issue these commands using the Command Window:

path1 = getenv('PATH')
path1 = [path1 ':/usr/local/bin']
setenv('PATH', path1)
!echo $PATH
```

If you restart MATLAB, the folder is no longer on the system path visible to MATLAB.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/creating-opening-changing-and-deleting-files-and-folders.html#f0-38522